# Entity Framework - Use Join clause on an entity collection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm a beginner beginner with entity framework and I need your help to build a query.

I have the following tables :

**table1**

```
idTable1  myDataTable1
```

**table2**

```
idTable2 myDataTable2 #idTable1 #idTable3
```

**table3**

```
idTable3 myDataTable3
```

I need to have an equivalent of the following sql request :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    WHERE t1.idTable1 = t2.idTable1 
        and t2.idTable3 = 4;
```

I try to do this with entityframework like that but it doesn't work :

```
List<table1> l = context.table1.Where(tab => (tab.table2.idTable3 == 4)).ToList<table1>();
```

The problem is that "table2" is an EntityCollection, I need to choose one with "ElementAt" to call "idTable3", but I want to search in all table2 elements...

Have you any idea ?

Regards

Edit :
At the moment, I use the following Linq query but if you have some ideas...

```
from t1 in context.table1 from t2 in t1.table2 where t2.table3.idTable3 == 4 select t1
```

Comment: You're query looks fine. What exception or unexpected result are you getting? BTW, passing a type to the ToList function at the end is unnecessary.

Comment: I have no exception because I can not build my project. table2 is an EntityCollection, when I type "tab.table2." the auto-completion doesn't propose any properties of my entity "table2".

Comment: Let me get this straight. The `table2` property on your `table1` object is a collection?

Comment: Yes, it is. table1 object have following properties : idTable1, EntityCollection<table2>. And table3 object have the same : idTable3, EntityCollection<table2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = context.table1.Where(x => x.table2.Any(y => y.idTable3 == 4)).ToList();
```